# Can I disable comment notifications on an uploaded YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, notifications

Is is possible to disable comment notifications for a specific video I've uploaded? I can't find any way to do it through YouTube's settings.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.youtube.com/account_notifications has a setting regarding "Activity on my videos or channel". This disables notifications for all videos though; there currently is no way to do this on a per-video setting.